How to Maintain local Flutter Packages?
I have created a Flutter project that contains several custom reusable packages. The code for these packages is hosted on GitHub. My main concern is how to effectively maintain these packages, including fixing bugs, managing older versions, and handling versioning and updates.
Edited : These are private packages and cannot be published.

It is not clear what you mean by local packages since they are hosted on GitHub. Do you mean private packages that are not meant to be published?

@DanR Yes, they are private and can't be published.

In that case, I would recommend amending the title.

You can upload and manage any package you have developed in pub.dev see:
https://dart.dev/tools/pub/publishing
